# Why the bridge(layer2) need a IP address?

Tags: centos, networking

I read a [doc](https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_30508309/article/details/97302152) in the Internet, there is a snapshot of the document's network topology:

[image]

As we know a bridge is layer2, it shouldn't have a IP address.

if the network namespaces want to access the Internet, it should through the bridge.
how to implement this function?

---

**EDIT-01**

in the document there is a command:

```
$ sudo ip addr add 10.0.1.0/24 dev mybridge0
```

is it mean config the ip 10.0.1.0/24 to mybridgen0?

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding the diagram. The bridge doesn't have an IP address; it shows a connection to the subnet 10.0.1.0/24.

Comment: Do you mean the command in my EDIT-01 is not configure a IP to bridge but special the subnet?

Comment: Despite reading a [translation of the document](https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=en&tab=TT&authuser=0&sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.csdn.net%2Fweixin_30508309%2Farticle%2Fdetails%2F97302152) I have no idea at all why the author wanted to assign a subnet to the bridge device. That makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: the bridge can assign IP address, so the `bridge0` can be regard as layer3 for checking whether netns can communicate with the `bridge0`.

Comment: Assigning 10.0.1.0/24 to the bridge won't allow it to be reached as an IPv4 host (rather than just bridging), because other systems (at least if they run Linux) will have a broadcast route to 10.0.1.0/24 (hidden in their "table local"), thus will ignore traffic coming from 10.0.1.0 (and will broadcast traffic sent to it instead of doing an ARP to resolve it).